# Flutter - Scrollable layout (Form with map)

Tags: dictionary, flutter, scrollable

I´m tring to create a simple form with a map. This [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJWdi.png) need to be scrolleable to show map (**Flexible** element, ignore Google Play Service alert). I try to use *SingleChildScrollView* and *Slivers* but i don´t understand how exactly works.

```
 return Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldKey,
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            body: orientation == Orientation.landscape
                ? new Row(children: <Widget>[map])
                : new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new ListView(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new SafeArea(child: instalationDropdown),
                          alias,
                          new Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          new Text(
                              DemoLocalizations.of(context).trans('datameter'),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          datameter,
                          new Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          new Text(DemoLocalizations.of(context).trans('meter'),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          contador,
                          makerDropdown,
                          modeloDropdown,
                          other,
                          new Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                          next,
                        ],
                      ),
                      map
                    ],
                  ),
```

So the question is: ¿How can i convert this layout in scrollable? It is useful too if the map is a fixed element and only the form has scroll.

**UPDATE 2**

If I use **SingleChildScrollView** return [blank view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j2vv.png).

Answer (score 0):

try to use Expand Wiedget for the map function

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

```
SingleChildScrollView (
        child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                         ...
                  ]),
           )
```